# Wrapping AngularStrap Popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm trying to wrap angular strap's popover with a custom directive.

The popover should be able to use a custom template provided by who is using my directive and the template should be able to use the scope of the controller.

For the scope part I found I can pass to $popover service the scope of the controller.

```
var myPopover = $popover(element, {
                title: 'My Title',
                placement : 'top',
                contentTemplate: 'example.html',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                autoClose: true,
                scope: scope
            });
```

Here is a plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/9vTzR0fKcjOlP0bNjZUf?p=preview

Is anybody able to explain me why the two buttons are opening the same popover? Should I isolate the scope? If yes, how could I use then the scope of the original controller to bind the variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is anybody able to explain me why the two buttons are opening the same popover?

Because both `customPopover` directives share the same scope. You want to instruct directive to create isolated scope for individual directive.

Add `scope: true`:

```
app.directive("customPopover", ["$popover", "$compile", function($popover, $compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var myPopover = $popover(element, {
                title: 'My Title',
                placement : 'top',
                contentTemplate: 'example.html',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                autoClose: true,
                scope: scope
            });

            scope.showPopover = function() {
                myPopover.show();
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2esMcQSLjDxdj7zESXD2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is that each time you use customPopover it sets scope.showPopover. Since the two instances in this case both share the same scope you are in a situation where the first scope.showPopover is written, then the directive is used a second time and scope.showPopover is written over with a version that points to the second element.

The solution to this is actually very simple. Since you have access to the element in the link function you can actually just add a click handler there and not have to worry about dealing with scope collisions like that. This also makes your directive more self-contained. Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGLJ3WiVnGfRXfM3die8?p=preview) that uses `element.on` instead of going through scope and using ngClick.